# XCode : Define Small thumbnail beside file?

Tags: xcode4.2

When xcode auto completes source in editor, if control+Spacebar is pressed pops up a small window with all relevant info like method with thumbnail (M)/class with thumbnail (C)/enum  with thumbnail (K), define  with thumbnail (#). Any xcode documentation mentioning what is meaning of each icon/thumbnail associated?and relevant details?

Similarly, in debug view of Xcode, I see stack frame with different icon -- like blank human portrait frame for main, setting icons for thread --  beside each file (Not SVM related icons like "A-added", "M-modified").